# c++ char array size validation

Tags: c++, validation, character-arrays

I have a character array that can hold 1000 elements (+1 for the '\0'). The array will be filled by user input. I was wondering if there is any way of checking if the input is more than what the array can hold. If I do try to add it, the program will crash before I can compare its size. I was thinking expand the array and see if the input is less than 1000 characters, but that idea doesn't seem like a really good one too me.

EDIT:

im using `std::cin.getline()` to get input from the user 
and can't use the `Sting` class

Comment: How are you filling the array? Please give your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way to check it is to find the index of `\0` in your array. If the position is equal or greater than `1000`, then you should not add more chars to it.

If you are using `cin.getline()` you can use a variable `n` to specify the maximum of chars you want

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

Here you can set `n=1001` (it also counts the termination char `\0`).

Comment: I'm using `cin.getline()` so all the input is immediatly stored in the array. It's not too important but It's for an assignment and my prof loves slashing 60% off anything that he can find wrong.

Comment: @JosipDorvak You could just use `std::string`.

Comment: Ok i wasn't sure it counted the termination character I'll try it out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  yes.

Use `std::string`:

```
std::string line
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    // do something with line
}
```

If you are not allowed to use `std::string`, then you can either role your own string class, or look at common implementations of `std::getline` and mimic them (just without storing it in a `std::string`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know an actual string would work. But our prof doesn't want us using strings. Really inconvenient. I'm just being overly protected no that he may "try" to overflow the array

Comment: Of course he's going to try to overflow the array.  That is probably one of the major points of this assignment.